# jQuery image replacement animation (mimic animated gif)

Tags: jquery, image, animation, replace

I have a sequence of JPGS in the form of:

```
Logo_1001.jpg
Logo_1002.jpg
Logo_1003.jpg
Logo_1004.jpg
Logo_1005.jpg
...
all the way to
Logo_1208.jpg
```

I am trying to change the source of the images every second (roughly) to mimic an animated gif, using these JPGs. This animation starts when they click on the image.

Here is what im working with so far, although im sure it could be coded better.

Also, it isnt really working so well right now ;x

```
function StartAnimation() {
    var name = $('#logo').attr('src');
    var index = name.indexOf(".jpg");

    var int = name.slice(index-4,index);

    while(int<1208){
        int++;

        var newname=name.slice(0,index-4);
        newname=newname+int;
        name=newname+".jpg";

        $('#logo').attr('src',name).delay(500);
    }
}

$("#logo").click(function() {
    StartAnimation()
});
```

Thoughts? Aid?

Thanks

Comment: What is the reasoning behind this usage?

Comment: Using an actual animated GIF on the iPhone produces poor results. Very choppy and the GIF quality looks poor.I wanted to see how things would render if I animated with JPGs and jQuery instead.Consider this an experiment, of sorts. If I can get this working smoothly in a standard browser, I will then test it on the iPhone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just got this working using setTimeout.

```
$("#logo").click(function() {
    var $logo = $(this), src = $logo.attr("src");
    var index = src.indexOf('.jpg');
    var step = +src.slice(index-4, index);

    function frame() {
        step++;
        if(step < 1050) {
            var newSrc = src.slice(0, index-4) + step + ".jpg";
            console.log(newSrc);
            $logo.attr('src', newSrc);
            setTimeout(frame, 1000);
        }
    }

    frame();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DgZ4M/

The problem with your script was in the use of `.delay`. It's only useful when chaining jQuery UI animations, not arbitrary delays. The jQuery documentation clearly says that

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

Comment: Thanks for this, ill try it out in my case and get back.

Comment: when am clicking on #logo the images the first image didnt changes it stays, in inspect element i see that src is changed but cant see it in action @Dogbert.Could you help me pls?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way, not "jQuery" per se.

```
var _animation_timer;
function LogoAnimate (go, num) {
    if (parseInt(num) == 'NaN' || parseInt(num) == undefined ||
        (_animation_timer == null && go != 'go') || go == 'stop')
    {
        clearTimeout(_animation_timer);
        return;
    }
    if (num >= 1208 || num < 1001) {
        num = 1001;
    }
    //$('#logo').attr('src','Logo_'+num+'.jpg');
    $('#logo').text('Logo_'+num+'.jpg');
    num++;
    _animation_timer = setTimeout('LogoAnimate("go","'+num+'")',1000);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var _images_preloaded = [];
    for (i = 1001; i <= 1208; i++) {
        _images_preloaded[i] = new Image();
        _images_preloaded[i].src = 'Logo_'+i+'.jpg';
    }
});
```

Demonstration markup:

```
<div id="logo">Not started.</div>
<p>
 <a href="javascript:LogoAnimate('go','1001');">Start</a> - 
 <a href="javascript:LogoAnimate('stop');">Stop</a>
</p>
```

Note, since I don't have that many images, my test just involved changing the text. You would just need to remove the quoted line and remove the line below using $.text(). Not also I assume you can figure out the $.click() part.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you need to preload all the images. Second - doing animations with sequence of jpgs is a bad idea :)

Comment: I am aware this is probably a bad idea. I still want to attempt it to confirm the animation quality.

Comment: Any hint why it might be a bad idea? Sounds like a good idea to me, because JPEG compression is much better for photographic images (i.e. perceptual quality for the same file size) than GIFs. (While other formats are not as widely supported in browsers.) Having said that, in either case the animation must be lightweight, maybe 20 frames, rather than 1000.